# Insert Org-id Link at Point via Outline Path Completion

Tags: org-mode

Currently to insert internal org-mode org-id links, I navigate to a heading or pull it up in agenda view (C-a s heading test search RET), store the link with C-l (org-store-link), going back to where I want to insert the link, then insert the link with C-c C-l (org-insert-link).

Instead, I would prefer to map a key that allows me to insert a link at 
the current point using tab completion similar to org-refile (C-c C-w). The intended result would be an org-id internal link in the form:

```
[[id:d7534b2f-c221-4dea-8566-d5ce3e4e1b78][Example Link]]
```

Looking through org-id.el, it seems like org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion was designed for this purpose. I tried:

```
(global-set-key "\C-ci" (lambda () (interactive) (org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion)))
```

but it didn't work as intended.

I have the following in my init.el file:

```
;; Use global IDs
(require 'org-id)
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id t)

;; Update ID file .org-id-locations on startup
(org-id-update-id-locations)

;; Refile options
(setq org-refile-targets (quote ((nil :maxlevel . 9) (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 9))))
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps t)
(setq org-refile-allow-creating-parent-nodes t)
```

Comment: You're missing a "-" in `org-id-get-with outline-path-completion`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not--it was just a typographical error. I've updated the question.

Comment: Too bad.  How is it failing? It works when I try it.

Comment: The function is definitely called. It prompts me for the entry, allows me to navigate via tab completion (which is great and works as intended), but when I hit enter, instead of pasting the link, it just moves the cursor to the the current headline, similar to C-c C-u (outline-up-heading).

Comment: I thought this may have been caused by an outdated org version, but tried the most recent in Emacs 24.5 so it must be something in my configuration. Can anyone confirm that my code above actually inserts a link for them?

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to insert a link, it just returns the id and you have to format the link yourself.  Moving the cursor sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I poked around in the org-mode source and found a minimally [documented](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html#fn-5) feature.  If you define a function `org-TYPE-complete-link`, it will be used to provide completion for links of type `TYPE`.  So we just need to define a function `org-id-complete-link` that does our completion and returns the link (including the "id:" prefix).

```
(defun org-id-complete-link (&optional arg)
  "Create an id: link using completion"
  (concat "id:"
          (org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion)))
```

Insert the link the normal way (with `C-c C-l`), select "id:" as the type and the completion function will fire.

EDIT:
As of `org-mode` version 9.0 just defining the function as above above no longer works ([ref](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#orga95073a)).  Instead you have to add the completion function to `org-link-parameters` using

```
(org-link-set-parameters "id"
                         :complete 'org-id-complete-link)
```

Comment: This is excellent and works as intended! The only modification I made was to add org-refile-targets as an argument to org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion. That way, I can can grab links from ANY of my org files. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sk8ingdom Can you update the question to include your final solution? I'm not sure what the doc means by `TARGETS may be a setting for ‘org-refile-targets’ to define eligible headlines.`

Comment: The final solution is just to define the function above and also call `org-link-set-parameters` if you're using `org-mode` 9.  The extra argument to `org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion` let's you limit the headlines you chose from just like `org-refile-targets` does when you refile.  See the help for everything, but a common setting is `((org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 3) (nil :maxlevel . 2))` which limits to 3 levels deep in agenda files and 2 in the current buffer.