# How to suggest org-link description when completing?

Tags: completion, org-link

I have a custom org link created using `org-link-set-parameters`. If I use `org-insert-link` and complete it will use the `:complete` function from the parameters to get the link. However I haven't found a clean way to then suggest a description based on the completed link. Do you have any suggestions?

There is `org-link-make-description-function` but that needs to be set before calling `org-insert-link` (I think?) and thus it isn't suitable for an emacs package. I tried `let`-binding it inside the `:complete` function, but that didn't work.

One thing I tried which did work, but seems a bit hacky was to add the following at the end of the `:complete` function:

```
(let ((link "mylink:this is my link"))
  (push link org-link--insert-history)
  (push `(,link "My description") org-stored-links)
  link)
```

Due to the way `org-insert-link` works this will get the description from `org-stored-links`. However it would then not insert the link into `org-link--insert-history`, so that's why I do that above.

Comment: [Details on setting a custom link completion function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/insert-org-id-link-at-point-via-outline-path-completion).