# Insert org mode links via helm-mini or refile (or equivalently using e.g. company mode)

Tags: org-mode, helm, company-mode

I often want to insert a link to another file (that would be easily accessible via helm-mini or refile). I have to do this long dance of going into the target file (and potentially headline), storing a link, going back to the original file, and inserting the link).

Is there a better way to do this? Either with helm, or company mode, or even via simple hack which chains these actions together. (The ideal would be just start with some target characters like [[ and simply have autocomplete, but a helm operation is good too!)

The closest thing I've found is this, but it does other things which I'm not interested in: [Insert Org-id Link at Point via Outline Path Completion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/insert-org-id-link-at-point-via-outline-path-completion)

Comment: `C-c C-l  file:` should open whatever completion system you normally use to find files. In what way is that not doing what you want?